# cout is declared in iostream, but where it is defined?

Tags: c++, stl

When I try to see definition of cout, I land to iostream file where it is declared as,

```
extern _CRTDATA2 ostream cout;
```

So where it is defined? Because extern is just declaration and not definition.

Comment: Somewhere in your standard library's source code rather than header files, probably?

Comment: @Mat Is STL open source?

Comment: There are several open-source implementations of the C++ standard library. Whether you're using one of them or not I can't tell.

Comment: The standard library is not STL. STL was from where much of the standard library was derived, but the two are quite different.

Comment: But to be a bit more on topic, why do you care where it is defined?

Comment: @StoryTeller Now I really do not understand this story. So if I am writing std::, don't I refer to STL in C++?

Comment: @StoryTeller I am looking for it because, I am making Video tutorial for cout, where I wanted to explain why one should use cout instead of printf like functions. And also want to cover some internals of cout, so it would be really helpful to should how it is declared and defined.

Comment: Have a read at this [STL is Not the CPP...](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StlIsNotTheCppStandardLibrary). When you write `std::` you refer to the namespace where the standard library is defined.

Comment: @StoryTeller I just read suggested article.  So when I must be saying I am using STL or not. Because I use std::map, std::string, std::vector,cout etc assuming I am using STL.

Comment: But you do not, you are using the standard library. Again, not the same thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33856/discussion-between-ppk-and-storyteller)

Comment: @ppk Why do you care so much if it's called STL or not? Well, it isn't, the standard library is just the standard library; that's what's it's always been, that's what you're always using. STL is not the abbreviation for "STandard Library", nor is it the same thing. `std` on the other hand, is. Now what's there to be confused about?

Comment: @MrLister Well I had that confusion. From where did it came? I don't know. Secondly, it is always good to know what you are using.. otherwise, c++ has so many things you cannot distinguish what to use and what not to. Like you can use C++/CLI and C++ Native at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global symbols are defined in a run-time library that you link with your applications. For example, in `gcc` you pass the compiler option `-lstdc++` that will link your application with the `libstdc++.a` library. That is where all such symbols reside.

Though, this is specific to your compiler/run-time library version and will vary. Microsoft Visual C++ may behave differently but the idea is the same: the symbols are inside the precompiled libraries that are delivered with your C++ compiler.

With GNU you can type:

```
nm -g libstdc++.a
```

to see the symbols inside the library. The output may look like this (among lots of other lines):

```
ios_init.o:
                 U _ZSt3cin
globals_io.o:
0000000000000000 D _ZSt3cin
0000000000000000 D _ZSt4cerr
0000000000000000 D _ZSt4clog
0000000000000000 D _ZSt4cout
0000000000000000 D _ZSt4wcin
0000000000000000 D _ZSt5wcerr
0000000000000000 D _ZSt5wclog
0000000000000000 D _ZSt5wcout
```