# In C++, where is std::cin object defined?

Tags: c++, iostream

In C++, the istream object `std::cin` is declared in header `<iostream>`, but where is it defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cout is declared in iostream, but where it is defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772732/cout-is-declared-in-iostream-but-where-it-is-defined)

Answer (score 11):

Where it is defined is not mandated by the standard, it's completely up to the implementation.

Here's where mine is:

```
$ nm -C /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -w cin
0000000000305900 B std::cin
```

Answer (score 3):

The implementation you're using provides them in some form. The specifics as to *where* they are at runtime is implementation-defined, but access *to* them is standard-defined. Their lifetimes and behavior therein are likewise defined by the standard:

> C++11 § 27.4.1(2)
>
> The objects are constructed and the associations are established at some time prior to or during the first time an object of class ios_base::Init is constructed, and in any case before the body of `main` begins execution.<sub>294</sub> The objects are not destroyed during program execution.<sub>295</sub> The results of including `<iostream>` in a translation unit shall be as if `<iostream>` defined an instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration. Similarly, the entire program shall behave as if there were at least one instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

In a library that is automatically linked to your executable by the compiler driver program (e.g. `g++` or `clang++`).

Answer (score 1):

Its a Object of class `istream`. So when you use `cin` you just create a `istream` type object.
It has external linkage and static duration.

The standard input stream is a source of characters determined by the environment. It is generally assumed to be input from an external source, such as the `keyboard` or a `file`.

As an object of class `istream`, characters can be retrieved either as formatted data using the extraction operator (`operator>>`) or as unformatted data, using member functions such as `read`.