# Where is the source code for `cout` defined?

Tags: c++, iostream

Where is the code for `cout` defined in the C++ standard library?

I'm looking in `libstdc++-v3/include/std/iostream/`, but the only entry in the file is `extern ostream cout;` in the file.

Where are the actual expressions that show where `cout` interacts with the system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cout is declared in iostream, but where it is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772732/cout-is-declared-in-iostream-but-where-it-is-defined)

Comment: It's defined by the compiler, which calls a function that is ultimately defined by the operating system, or in whatever environment you're running.

Comment: I want to say it's allocated here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/globals_io.cc (as a punned char array!?) and initialized here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/ios_init.cc (placement new)

Comment: @parktomatomi libc++ does it the same way: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/iostream.cpp#L38. I don't think there are many other ways of doing it, since `cout` must have type `std::ostream`, `std::ostream` cannot be constant-initialized, but the library has to support initializing `std::cout` on-demand during static initialization at startup when an object of type `std::ios_base::Init` is created. I don't think there is any legal way that standard-conforming user code could implement this.

Comment: @walnut -- the standard library implementation does not have to be written in standard-conforming C++. Implementations often take advantage of known compiler behavior, compiler-specific hooks, internal undocumented functions, etc.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, that is why I wrote *user code*. And when talking about the implementation of `cout` in the standard library, I meant that this is probably one of the few reasonable ways of doing it without a compiler hook, only relying on some general guarantees of the compiler/linker (i.e. here that you can "pun" the type by declaring it differently in the `<iostream>` header for the user).

Comment: @PeteBecker But of course I am speculating. Is there some other alternative (not necessarily standard-conform user code, but only relying on general behavior of usual implementations) to implement `std::cout` in the standard library that wouldn't require special support by the compiler and/or linker?

Comment: @walnut -- the `Init` requirement is a formalization of the "nifty counter" trick that Jerry Schwarz invented to ensure that stream objects would be initialized before any possible use. That solves the problem of code that writes to `std::cout` from the constructor of a static object. But in big systems, those `Init` objects are scattered all over the place, and can lead to slow startup when memory pages that aren't otherwise used get pulled into memory. Internally, compilers and linkers can cooperate to avoid this simply by initializing `std::cout` before initializing any static objects.